# How to calculate two asp text box values using JavaScript and save it on database?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetimepicker

I have two text boxes which take date time value and the date time is setting from Bootstrap DateTimePicker. Now i want to subtract two date time values using JavaScript and save it in database?

Here is my code of date time pickers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=datetimeCreated.ClientID %>").datetimepicker({
                calendarWeeks: true,
                useCurrent: false,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',

            });

            $("#datetimeCreated").on('dp.change', function (e) {
                var date = $("#datetimeCreated").val();

            });

        });


        $(function () {
            $("#<%=datetimeClosed.ClientID%>").datetimepicker({
                calendarWeeks: true,
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            });

            $("#datetimeClosed").on('dp.change', function (e) {
                var date = $("#datetimeClosed").val();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please provide the code you've got for this project, so when can guide you more directly towards an answer.

Comment: Why not do the subtract server side?

Comment: Okay, how to do it from server side?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the diff using moment.js (which is already required for datetimepicker) like this:

```
var diff = moment.duration(date1.diff(date2)).asDays();
```

Read more about [`.duration()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) and [`.diff()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) in the docs.

Read the code and let me know if something is not clear.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1, #datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
  
  $('button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var date1 = $('#datetimepicker1').data('DateTimePicker').date();
    var date2 = $('#datetimepicker2').data('DateTimePicker').date();
    var diff = moment.duration(date1.diff(date2)).asDays();
    // here is what are you looking for:
    console.log(diff);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.44/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.44/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should probably link to moment.js docs and mention that you're suggesting to use it there in the answer.

Comment: @IvanKolmychek moment.js is required when using bootstrap-datetimepicker

Comment: Still, in your answer you're using its API directly to do what OP asks for; providing any links to where you got the info about that API from (and where OP can actually look up other related stuff, moment is a pretty awesome library) can be beneficial. But that's only my humble opinion ofc. :)